# How to use environment variables once declared

Tags: ruby

I am trying to an use an environment variable as an API key, but once when using it. The ruby interpreter gives me constant un initialised error. Can anyone draw some light on this. I seem to find no resource explaining how to use them after declaration. Here is my code

```
require 'httparty'

class Recipe
  include HTTParty

  ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY'] = 'key'  
  base_uri 'http://food2fork.com/api'
  default_params key: FOOD2FORK_KEY
  format :json

  def self.for term
    get("", query: { q: term})
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access environment variables inside Ruby with the [`ENV` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/ENV.html).

```
default_params key: ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY']
```

You generally shouldn't be setting environment variables inside a Ruby application, except maybe for testing. They should be set by the system calling your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I overlooked -> in the documentation as hash rocket :(

Comment: can you give me some example regarding the system calling your application part

Comment: @gates Sure. You put things like API keys in environment variables so they're not hard coded in the program or written to a file on disk for flexibility and security reasons. When you start the application, you set the FOOD2FORK_KEY environment variable in your shell like `$ FOOD2FORK_KEY=deadbeef ruby -e 'puts ENV["FOOD2FORK_KEY"]'`.

Comment: @gates No, environment variables are set by your shell.  `KEY=value ruby app.rb` if you're using bash (which you probably are).

Comment: If I use cmd in Windows?

Comment: @gates I think you have to [`SET FOOD2FORK_KEY=deadbeef`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#DOS.2C_OS.2F2_and_Windows) and then run the program.

Answer (score 3):

You should use it like this `ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY']`. This will return the value of the given key. See details here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/ENV.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I overlooked -> in the documentation as hash rocket :(